# Pagereference not redirecting to Currentpage with the Saved values

Tags: pagereference

My VF page is

```
<apex:PageBlock title="Letters" mode="inlineEdit"  >
<apex:pageBlockButtons location="top" rendered="{!IF(TasklstI.size>0,true,false)}" >
    <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!saveTaskI}" id="saveButton"/>
    <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancelTask}" id="cancelButton"/> 
</apex:pageBlockButtons>
<apex:pageblockTable value="{!TasklstI}" var="tsk" rendered="{!IF(TasklstI.size>0,true,false)}" id="table">

<apex:column headerValue="Document Type"> <apex:outputfield value="{!tsk.HBC_Grp_Task_Document_Type__c}"/></apex:column>
<apex:column headerValue="Group #"><apex:outputField value="{!tsk.HBC_Group_Num__c}"/></apex:column>
</apex:pageblockTable>
</apex:pageblock>
```

My Apex class for save and cancel is

```
   Public pagereference saveTaskI(){    
        Upsert tasklstI;
        ownerhide = false;

        pagereference pp = new pagereference('/apex/RecertificationDetails?id='+apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id'));
        pp.setredirect(true);
        return pp;
      //return apexpages.currentpage(); the saved values are not displaying in the page
    }
    public pagereference cancelTask(){
         Pagereference pg = new pagereference('/apex/RecertificationDetails?id='+apexPages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id')); 
        pg.setredirect(true);
        return pg;
        //return apexpages.currentpage(); the values are not reverting back in the page
    }
```

I don't want to use such a lengthy code as it effects the performance.But If I use `return apexpages.currentpage();`  the page is not working as expected . Am I missing anything?

Comment: for using this, `apexpages.currentpage();` you should also use `apexpages.currentpage().getParameters.put('id',recordId);` to set the updated value.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more as I'm not putting these recordid anywhere

Comment: Refer the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though you want to use `return apexpages.currentpage();`, You've to set Page paramters. Refer below example:

```
PageReference pageRef = ApexPages.CurrentPage();
Apexpages.Currentpage().getParameters.put('id',ApexPages.Currentpage().getparameters().get('id'));
pageRef.setRedirect(true);
return pageRef;
```

**Other method**

```
pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/RecertificationDetails');
pageRef.setRedirect(true);
pageRef.getParameters().put('question',ApexPages.Currentpage().getparameters().get('id'));
return pageRef;
```

Comment: I just don't want to use those all lines. can i Just use like this `Public pagereference saveTaskI(){ return apexpages.currentpage(); } ` as I was in the same page

Comment: @EagerinSf As fas as I know. You can't do that because you need to setRedirect as true and update page parameters if you want to send any. That's how it works.